Why does $\sum_{p\leq x} \log^2p = Ax\log x+o(x\log x)$ in Erdős's proof of the PNT?
I am currently attempting to understand Erdős/Selberg's original elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem (using this publicly available version: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063042/pdf/pnas01544-0034.pdf). At the beginning of Lemma 2 he says that, given $\sum_{p\leq x} \log p = \vartheta(x) = Ax + o(x)$ it is a "simple computation" to show that $$\sum_{p\leq x} \log^2p = Ax\log x+o(x\log x).$$ How does one show this? I can see very easily that $\sum_{p\leq x} \log^2p \leq \sum_{p\leq x} \log p \log x = \vartheta(x)\log x = Ax\log x + o(x\log x)$ which gives $\sum_{p\leq x} \log^2p \leq Ax\log x + o(x\log x)$ but how do you show $\sum_{p\leq x} \log^2p =Ax\log x + o(x\log x)$?
I also see that the statement $\sum_{p\leq x} \log^2p = \vartheta(x)\log x + O(x)$ suffices, and many papers I have looked at seem to just take this as given. Is there a good elementary proof of this that I am missing?

What do you mean by "equality"? Little-o (and big-o) statements are inequalities by definition, the use of the equals sign is a (very common) abuse of notation.

Good point. I edited it to remove the word equality. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Wouldn't a constant satisfy one but not the other? E.g. $k\leq Ax\log x + o(x\log x)$ but not $k = Ax\log x + o(x\log x)$?

Hmm, the definition on Wikipedia doesn't agree with me. In any case, I am pretty sure Erdos only needs the inequality; try working through the rest of the argument under this assumption, I'd be surprised if you needed to know that this bound is tight. It's unfortunate that Erdos doesn't define his asymptotic notations.

Hmmm interesting. My understanding of little-o is this context is $f(x) = Ax\log x+o(x\log x)$ means $f(x) - Ax\log x = o(x\log x)$ or in other words for large enough $x$, $x\log x$ is much larger than $|f(x) - Ax\log x|$ (so if $f(x) = k$ then this is not true, since both have a growth rate of $x\log x$). The "Less than" I interpreted as there exists some $g(x) = o(x\log x)$ such that $f(x)\leq Ax\log x + g(x)$ for large enough x (in this case $g(x) = 0$ would work). Is that not correct?

Oh I just saw your comment. I'll take another look at it but I'm pretty sure the argument would only work if the inequality was in the other direction. I'll check again though.

I think I see what you are asking now but this could be made much more clear. Let $T(x)$ be the sum you are calculating. You are stating you are aware that $T(x) \le Ax \log x + o(x \log x)$ for some $A$. You want however the slightly stronger statement that $|T(x)-Ax \log x|$ is also $o(x \log x)$ i.e., you want to show that $T(x)$ cannot be anything like say $T(x) = A |\cos x|x \log x$. So you want both a fairly precise  lower bound as well as the upper bound [which you seem to see already] for $T(x)$. Is that right?

By Abel's summation formula: $$
\sum\limits_{p \le x} {\log ^2 p}  = \sum\limits_{p \le x} {\log p\log p}  = \vartheta (x)\log x - \int_1^x {\frac{{\vartheta (t)}}{t}{\rm d}t}  = \vartheta (x)\log x + \mathcal{O}(x),
$$ since $\vartheta(t)=\mathcal{O}(t)$.

We can compute this using Riemann-Stieltjes integral, as follows:
$
\sum_{p\leq x}(\log p)^2=\int_1^x \log t \,d(\theta(t))=\theta(x)\log x+O(1)-\int_1^x\frac{\theta(t)}{t}\,dt.
$
Using $\theta(x)=Ax+o(x)$, the first term in the RHS is $Ax\log x+o(x\log x)$, as $x\to \infty$. The integral is $O(x)$, as $x\to \infty$, so the claim follows.
